# Parsing a binary format in Crystal

Tags: crystal-lang

Given a binary format with a header that include the number of records and records of format:

`{ type : Int8, timestamp : UInt32, user_id : UInt64 }`

```
0000 0004 0153 0927 d139 6747 c045 d991
2100 53d1 6287 4fd2 69fd 8e5f 0475 0153
f323 a72b 4984 a40b 8d54 db00 53a0 78d4
1db8 b1a6 4129 1651
```

I'm coming from Ruby and I have the following solution which works, but I think there might be a more elegant or 'crystal' way to read the bytes when it's structured data?

```
class User
  USER_TYPES = {
    0 => :admin,
    1 => :user,
  }
  property user_type : Symbol
  property timestamp : UInt32
  property user_id : UInt64

  def initialize(user_type : Int8, @timestamp : UInt32, @user_id : UInt64)
    @user_type = USER_TYPES[user_type]
  end
end

class Parser
  property users : Array(User)

  def initialize
    @users = [] of User
  end

  def parse(file_path : String)
    File.open(file_path) do |file|
      offset = 0
      count : UInt32 = seek_and_unpack(file, offset, UInt32)
      offset += 4

      (0..count).each do |i|
        user_type = seek_and_unpack(file, offset, Int8)
        timestamp = seek_and_unpack(file, offset + 1, UInt32)
        user_id = seek_and_unpack(file, offset + 5, UInt64)
        user = User.new(user_type, timestamp, user_id)
        @users << user
        offset += 13
      end
      @users
    end
  end

  private def seek_and_unpack(file : File, offset : Int32, read_type)
    file.seek(offset)
    file.read_bytes(read_type, IO::ByteFormat::BigEndian)
  end
end

puts Parser.new.parse("my_file.dat")
# [#<User:0x102805fe0 @user_type=:user, @timestamp=1393108945, @user_id=4136353673894269217>,
# #<User:0x102805fc0 @user_type=:admin, @timestamp=1406231175, @user_id=5751776211841778805>,
# #<User:0x102805fa0 @user_type=:user, @timestamp=1408443303, @user_id=3119170057034093787>,
# #<User:0x102805f80 @user_type=:admin, @timestamp=1403025620, @user_id=2141656950430570065>]
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. The `#seek` calls are redundant sometimes (just use `IO#skip`) but it looks like the rest is good.

Comment: @RX14 ok cool thanks! didn't know about `IO#skip`

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of the seeks, since `read_bytes` already seeks the IO and wrap the unpack operation in a macro to make it more readable:

```
class Parser
  property users

  @users = [] of User

  def parse(path)
    File.open(path) do |file|
      count = unpack(UInt32)

      count.times do
        @users << User.new(
          user_type: unpack(Int8),
          timestamp: unpack(UInt32),
          user_id: unpack(UInt64)
        )
      end
      @users
    end
  end

  macro unpack(type)
    file.read_bytes({{type}}, IO::ByteFormat::BigEndian)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use https://github.com/spider-gazelle/bindata which is a little more declarative and also handles endianness for you.

```
require "bindata"

enum UserType
  Admin = 0
  User
end

class User < BinData
  endian big

  enum_field UInt8, type : UserType = UserType::User
  uint32 :timestamp
  uint64 :user_id
end

users = [] of User
File.open(path) do |file|
  count = file.read_bytes(UInt32, :big_endian)

  count.times do
    users << file.read_bytes(User)
  end
end
users
```

Answer (score 0):

There multiple possibilities to make your code as you described it more 'crystal'

You could use `IO#read` instead of `IO#seek` and `IO#read_bytes`:

```
def parse(file_path : String)
  File.open(file_path, "rb") do |file|
    count : UInt32 = file.read(UInt32).first
    
    (0..count).each do |i|
      user_type = file.read(Int8).first
      timestamp = file.read(UInt32).first
      user_id = file.read(UInt64).first
      user = User.new(user_type, timestamp, user_id)
      @users << user
    end
    @users
  end
end
```

Adding to this you could use `IO#each_slice` to iterate over the records of the file instead of incrementing an offset

```
def parse(file_path : String)
  File.open(file_path, "rb") do |file|
    count : UInt32 = file.read(UInt32).first
    
    file.each_slice(13) do |slice|
      user_type = slice[0]
      timestamp = slice[1..4].pack("C*").unpack(UInt32).first
      user_id = slice[5..12].pack("C*").unpack(UInt64).first
      user = User.new(user_type, timestamp, user_id)
      @users << user
    end
    @users
  end
end
```

You could also use `IO#each_struct` so you can directly unpack the records into a struct:

```
struct Record
  type : Int8
  timestamp : UInt32
  user_id : UInt64
end

def parse(file_path : String)
  File.open(file_path, "rb") do |file|
    count : UInt32 = file.read(UInt32).first
    
    file.each_struct(Record) do |record|
      user_type = USER_TYPES[record.type]
      timestamp = record.timestamp
      user_id = record.user_id
      user = User.new(user_type, timestamp, user_id)
      @users << user
    end
    @users
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, @noah1400! I stumbled upon your answer in a search and got hooked. Could you tell me where you saw the description of `each_struct` and `unpack` methods in Crystal?